# Searching a linked list with O(1)

Tags: java, linked-list, hashtable

I was in an interview and I was asked about hashtable and I had to explain structural chaining.

I was asked how to search for an element in the linked list with O(1) complexity.

Can we actually find with O(1)?

Thanks

Comment: Put all the elements in a hashset?

Comment: asslias, you are correct, but adding the elements to the hashset is O(n) :)

Comment: @ilanberci Yes, but you only have to do it once for multiple lookups.

Comment: Was the interviewer seeing if you knew whether it was possible, or how to actually do it?

Comment: That is what i was thinking O(n) is the right answer and beat my head around for O(1)

Answer (score 9):

No, absolutely not. A linked list has no cunning way of finding an item quickly - it's O(n).

Searching in a hashtable is only O(1) if you have good enough hash codes. If *all* your keys have the same hash code, it's O(n) whatever addressing scheme you use.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Not from this answer I don't - at least not unless it's accepted.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you stop getting rep from upvotes after a certain point?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Indeed - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63327/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are keeping a reference to your nodes in the linked list in some other structure, you cannot access an element in the linked list in O(1). This is because a linked list keeps a reference to the head of the list and must iterate through each next element to find the one requested, which comes out to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot search in Linked list within O(1) complexity.

Hashtable creates the structure chaining or linked list of elements with same hash value.

If hashes are uniformly distributed (good hash) then hash table would have O(1) complexity for searching elements. Hash table has buckets each bucket can be accessed from the hash value then each bucket contains linked-list of elements with same hash-value.

http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Chaining